# Obtaining Wadler's lectures and materials on Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a place where I can download all of [Wadlers Lectures on Haskell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOl2y5uW0mA&list=PL4C1D41CB47EED318) in this series in one fell swoop? Also where can I find any available written/computer materials?

Comment: Could you find it? Do you know the reason why it is gone?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if those videos are available anywhere else, but there are websites that allow you to easily download Youtube videos if you would like. One method I found on Google: http://www.4kdownload.com/howto/howto-download-youtube-playlist

The slides are here: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf1/fp/lectures/2011/lect01.pdf

Materials are here: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf1/fp/

Those materials are actually from 2012 when someone else taught the class, so the exercises may not be the same ones Wadler used. You can find the 2011 exams and programming competition on that page, though.

Also, fair warning, the consensus [on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/15r6x3/video_lectures_of_a_class_on_haskell_and/) seems to be that Wadler is not actually a great teacher, at least for beginners. If you're just looking for an intro to Haskell or functional programming, there are almost definitely better and more effective resources out there.